# how to auto scroll with timer in page view controller in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, timer, uipageviewcontroller, autoscroll

Hi  I just want to scroll pages in page view controller automatically with timer in swift 3 - so after I read similar questions I used this Extension code to auto scroll in page view controller But It Didn't worked for me

here is the Extension Code

```
extension pageVC2 {
func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let currentViewController = viewControllers?[0] {
        if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) {
            setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
}
```

and then I tried Another answer so I used This code But I will get Error with ScrollView

Here is the second way that I tried

```
func moveToNextPageTwoSecond (){

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame)
    let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * 4
    let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x

    var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth

    if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth{
        slideToX = 0
    }
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(slideToX, 0, pageWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)), animated: true)
}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(pageVC2.moveToNextPageTwoSecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }
```

Comment: heck my ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668536/uipageviewcontroller-automatic-scrolling-in-ios/34505406#34505406), it was working fine for me. Its in Objective-C , logic will be same for Swift3 as well.

Comment: can you convert it to swift and write that here? please

Comment: I wiil update and let you know :)

Comment: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/ will do most of the heavy lifting for objC -> Swift conversions.